# MySQL: Full-text search in boolean mode not working as expected

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm having problems with MySQL's full-text search feature in boolean mode. The query I want to run is the following:

```
SELECT v.id v_id,
    v.duration v_duration,
    v.title v_title,
    v.description v_description
FROM videos v
JOIN videos_search_text vst ON vst.video_id = v.id
WHERE MATCH(vst.search_text) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

If I replace the `?` with `"+the +black* +key*"`, I get no results. However, if I remove the "+" before "the", and search for `"the +black* +key*"`, I get about 100 results, which is correct. But all of the returned results contain "the" in them... So why does the first string return no results?

Note: I set the minimum word length to 1 in case that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED:**

The problem was that MySQL doesn't include stopwords (such as "the") in full-text indexes. So in the first string it's not included as part of the search phrase and results for `"+black* +key*"` are returned. If you try to force "the" (or any other stopword) to be included in the search by using the `+` operator, no results are returned because "the" is not in the index being searched.

The solution that I took was disabling stopword filtering in the options file. Another solution you could probably take is to fetch all the stopwords form the database into your application and remove any occurrences of them in your search string before adding the `+` operator.